# jQuery expand Bootstrap panel on form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap

```
I have a collapsible panel in my form like this: 


     <form action="/add/57c6c1d5-9e8c-4f13-9b17-5b549a44812a" class="form-horizontal" id="JobAddForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">        
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                      <div class="form-group required has-warning">
                        <label for="JobPoNumber" class="col-md-4 control-label">PO Number</label>
                         <div class="col-md-8">
                           <input name="data[Job][po_number]" class="form-control" maxlength="255" type="text" id="JobPoNumber" required="required">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
         </form>
```

My input element with id `JobPoNumber` is a required field, however as it has the HTML5 required attribute, when the form is submitted the panel is collapsed so the required message never shows.

Is there a way I can expand all panels which have inputs that are required but not filled in on form submit?

Something like this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#JobAddForm').submit(function( event ) {
      $('input[required]')
      .closest(".panel").expand();
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you try `$('input[required]').closest(".panel").find('.panel-body').slideDown();$('input[required]').closest(".panel").removeClass('panel-collapsed');` instead of your `.expand()` ?

Comment: It doesn't hit that point because when I submit the form the HTML required errors prevent the form from submitting.